# Update single value in extjs template

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs

How can I update a single value of the Template´s data and re-render it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

One possible solution could be - merge the updated value in values object that would have been used earlier and then call the `.apply` on the template with this updated values object to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with amol

Other way could be to save the array loaded in the template so then you can update it and load again with your modification